# How to make UIDatePicker to show user selected time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatepicker where I am letting user chose time . `UITableview` is in a `UIView` where on click of a `UIButton` a `UIDdatePicker` appears, when the user choose a time and press back button to dismiss `UIDdatePicker` view and if he wants to check whats the time he had chose in `UIDdatePicker`. The `UIDdatePicker` doesn't show the time which the user had selected it shows the current time or the time start time of datepicker . **I want to display the time user has chosen by the user when he opens datepicker again.**
This is my code for when user press `UIButton` to display `UIDdatePicker` view

```
-(IBAction)settingsButtonChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{

    userTimePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [userTimePicker addTarget: self
                       action: @selector(userTimePickerValueChanged:)forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

This is my code which lets datepicker have custom time limit

```
-(IBAction)datepickerTimenButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control
{

    if (control.tag == 1)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        int startTime = 7;
        int endTime = 11;

        NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
        components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date1];

        [components setHour:startTime];;
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:endTime];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        morningButton.selected = YES;
        afternoonButton.selected = NO;
        eveningButton.selected = NO;
        nightButton.selected = NO;

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];

        [userTimePicker setDate:startDate animated:YES];
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

    }

    if (control.tag == 2)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        morningButton.selected = NO;
        afternoonButton.selected = YES;
        eveningButton.selected = NO;
        nightButton.selected = NO;

        int startTime = 12;
        int endTime = 15;

        NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
        components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date1];

        [components setHour:startTime];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:endTime];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];

        [userTimePicker setDate:startDate animated:YES];
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

    }
}
```

Code which lets user selects his own time

```
-(void) userTimePickerValueChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{

    switch (self.selectedButton)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            NSUserDefaults *userSelectedMorningTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSDate *selectedMorningTime = [userTimePicker date];

            NSLog (@"SETTING: morningTimeKey");

            storedMornTime = selectedMorningTime;

            [userSelectedMorningTime setObject:selectedMorningTime forKey:@"morningTimeKey"];
            [userSelectedMorningTime synchronize];
        }
            break;

        case 2:
        {
            NSUserDefaults *userSelectedAfternoonTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSDate *selectedAfternoonTime = [userTimePicker date];

            NSLog (@"SETTING: afternoonTimeKey");

            storedAfternoonTime = selectedAfternoonTime;

            [userSelectedAfternoonTime setObject:selectedAfternoonTime forKey:@"afternoonTimeKey"];
            [userSelectedAfternoonTime synchronize];
        }
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could make out from the code you are saving the selected time to `NSUserDefaults`, but you are never using the saved time back from it.

My guess that if you change that everything should work.

```
-(IBAction)datepickerTimenButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (control.tag == 1)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        int startTime = 7;
        int endTime = 11;

        //Saved Morning time date from user defaults
        NSDate *date1  = [defaults objectForKey:@"morningTimeKey"];
        if(!date1) date1 = [NSDate date];
        components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date1];

        [components setHour:startTime];;
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:endTime];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        morningButton.selected = YES;
        afternoonButton.selected = NO;
        eveningButton.selected = NO;
        nightButton.selected = NO;

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];

        [userTimePicker setDate:startDate animated:YES];
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

    }

    if (control.tag == 2)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        morningButton.selected = NO;
        afternoonButton.selected = YES;
        eveningButton.selected = NO;
        nightButton.selected = NO;

        int startTime = 12;
        int endTime = 15;

        //Saved AfterNoon time date from user defaults
        NSDate *date1  = [defaults objectForKey:@"afternoonTimeKey"];
        if(!date1) date1 = [NSDate date];

        components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date1];

        [components setHour:startTime];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:endTime];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];

        [userTimePicker setDate:startDate animated:YES];
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

    }
}
```

Comment: i shouldnt do reloadInputViews right and in setDate: shouldnt i pass date1 since it has the time chosen my user and when datepicker is open again it shows the user selected time

Comment: @raptor I couldn't fully understand your code, you should be using the date you stored in userDefaults, but you wanted to create a maximum date and minimum date. That why I kept rest of the code as such. Yes reloadInputViews is not needed.

Comment: @raptor If you want to create a min and max, instead of modifying the whole date, you can just create another date by adding the timeInterval to get maxDate for both morningTime and afternoonTime.

Comment: The code which you have modified should work right ..u r storing the user selected time in date1 ..so when I open datepicker ..it will show user selected time and reload input view code should be removed

Comment: @raptor It believe it should work. I haven't worked it out, If you can give more inputs like why are doing those calculations. I can help you better.

Comment: I just want to display user selected time in date picker when it is opened

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29439/discussion-between-anupdas-and-raptor)

Comment: I think I will have to pass date1 to set date: method

Comment: @raptor Yes you can just pass that. As I already mentioned, I maintained the code as much to what you were trying to do. If you want only that remove the dateComponents part, min max part etc.

Comment: @raptor I have worked out a [demo project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestDatePicker.zip), see if this is useful.

Comment: @raptor Are you talking about the demo project i send to you or your original one. Did you try the source code i send to you?

Comment: just one more thing in UIDatepicker i am displaying time in a given range when i open datepicker sometimes the time showed in unselected format( like the time is out of range) ..when i tap on datepicker then the time is displayed in bold ...why is that

Comment: @raptor The only time it can happen is when there is no stored values in NSUserDefaults. Can you test for this condition, like when the date1 is no there, for that condition is have put `[NSDate date]` you can put a suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

```
[datePicker setDate:date animated:YES];
```

pass current date with

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just save selected date in the variable. 
On showing dataPicker, just set that date.

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date]
[datePicker setDate:date animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For some reason setting the minimum date only for the date picker and not for the time picker solved my issue:

```
if ([datePicker isDatePicker]) {

    //DATE PICKER
    datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];

}else{

    //TIME PICKER

    //datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];

}
```